# Python pandas: unify datetime column format from CSV input

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a mixed format column in a dataframe from a pd.read_csv(). There is a lot of information out there about datetime handling but I didn't find anything for this specific problem:

2 datatime types:

1. Custom dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm that shows up in excel as such: 10/03/2018 07:18
2. General that shows up in Excel as such: 8/13/2018 2:28:34 PM

I used :

```
df.Last_Updated = pd.to_datetime(df['Last_Updated'])
df = df.sort_values('Last_Updated').drop_duplicates(['Name'], keep='last')
```

But I get a mixed bunch where the custom format returns as another datatime type :

3. yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss and shows up in my Excel export as 2017-11-22 19:54:35

Upon checking it changes the dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm (02/09/2018  17:55:44) format to yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss (2018-02-09 17:55:44) and since I have to perform an exclusion of the type 'older than' it causes errors; in this particular case, a computer that has it's last connection in September returns as having it in February.

Does anyone know a way to unify the datetime format?

Date format:

from notepad:

```
    X = "10/2/2018 10:07:31 PM"
    Y = "8/13/2018 2:28:34 PM"
```

from CSV (and by opening the .txt via Excel):

```
X = 10/02/2018 22:07 PM
Y = 8/13/2018 2:28:34 PM
```

after datetime applied in code:

```
X = 02/10/2018  22:07:31
Y = 13/08/2018  14:28:34
```

Comment: It's a little unclear what you are trying to say after the "mixed bunch" part. Can you give an example of what the data looks like in `df['Last_Updated']` before you run `pd.to_datetime`?

Comment: @shadowtalker point 1 and point 2

Comment: It looks like they only differ in that the 2nd one has seconds and an AM/PM indicator. Is that right?

Comment: Also, are the elements of the column actually strings, or is it a mix of strings and `datetime` objects?

Comment: @shadowtalker: 1 is a custom datetime format, 2 is a general format. Day and month are also inverted

Comment: Can you confirm that all the elements in the Series are `str` type?

Comment: @DarthVagrant can you show us an example of the csv file from notepad?

Comment: @Chris: updated

Comment: @DarthVagrant you wont be able to use a simple function and have it know when a date is formatted as dd/mm/yyyy vs mm/dd/yyyy. Unless another column has the format I do not think there is much you can do